# Claims lookup table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In asp.net identity model there are the tables AspNetRoleClaims and AspNetUserClaims which contain the foreign keys RoleId and UserId respectively and also the columns ClaimType and ClaimValue.
The question is why there is not a lookup table for the claims, a table which would contain Id and ClaimType or ClaimName and then we use a foriegn key for it in the tables AspNetRoleClaims and AspNetUserClaims?

Comment: Why would that be a good idea?  Claims can be anything, your table would be an intermediate step requiring maintenance.

Comment: In the current case, you would repeat the claim type with each user and role, you might mistype the claimtype when you write it many times.